# Preprocessor directives in C++

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

I have read several articles about how Preprocessor directives work in C++.
It's clear to me that Preprocessor directives are managed by the pre-processor before compilation phase.
Let's consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef N
#define N 10
#endif 

int main(){
int v[N];
return 0;
}
```

The Pre-processor will elaborate the source code by performing text replacement, so this code during compilation phase would be equivalent to:

```
int main(){
int v[10];
return 0;
}
```

Now my question is: Can I define a Macro by setting its value equal to a function?
It looks a bit weird to me but the answer is yes.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <limits>
#ifndef INT_MIN
#define INT_MIN std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
#endif
int get_max(){
    return 5;
}
#ifndef INT_MAX
#define INT_MAX get_max()
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << INT_MIN << " " << INT_MAX;
    return 0;
}
```

Conceptually I'm not understanding why this code works, the pre-processor have to replace text before compilation phase, so how could a function be invoked (In this case *get_max()* function) ?

Functions invoking is a task managed by compiler? isn't it?

How could Pre-processor get access to *std::numeric_limits::min()*? This value is present inside the *"limits"* library, but if I understand correctly the libraries's inclusion is done by compiler.

Comment: You'll get `std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << " " << get_max();` after a preprocessor does its job.

Comment: It doesn't. It replaces INT_MAX with the literal text `get_max()` and let's the compiler do its job.

Comment: Text replacement happens before actual compilation so if you replace the `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` macros by their value manually, then look at the code and then ask yourself the following question: Why would it not compile ? It is valid C++ (after the replacement).

Comment: ```INT_MIN``` and ```INT_MAX``` macros aren't replaced, they aren't present inside ```limits``` library. I'm just defining these two macros for the first time

Comment: You _can_ have the compiler invoke functions, but that doesn't use the preprocessor. Look up `constexpr`. From your example, `std::numeric_limits<int>::min` is such a `constexpr` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of illustration I removed the includes from your code:

```
#ifndef INT_MIN
#define INT_MIN 0
#endif
int get_max(){
    return 5;
}
#ifndef INT_MAX
#define INT_MAX get_max()
#endif

int main()
{
    return INT_MIN + INT_MAX;
}
```

Then I invoked gcc with `-E` to see the output after preprocessing:

```
int get_max(){
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    return 0 + get_max();
}
```

This is the code that will get compiled. The preprocessor does not call the funciton. It merely replaces `INT_MAX` with `get_max()`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E17xG5nM8)

> Can I define a Macro by setting its value equal to a function?

Thats not what you do. `#define INT_MAX get_max()` just tells the preprocessor to replace `INT_MAX` with `get_max()`. The preprocessor doen't know nor care if `get_max()` is a function call or something else.